# var numbers = document.querySelectorAll("#box1 , #box2");

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem with my javascript code
why that function didn't get the multiple id's

```
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll("#box1 , #box2");
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    var span = document.createElement('span')
    span.textContent = i;
    numbers.appendChild(span);
}
/////////////////////////
<div id="box1"></div>(this is the div where is doesn't get)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike jQuery you cannot run an action of the entire node list (array of elements). You have to `forEach` all the elements.

```js
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll("#box1 , #box2");
numbers.forEach(function(number) {

  // this is almost exact copy of your code
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement('span')
    span.textContent = i;
    number.appendChild(span);
  }

})
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use getElementById?

use querySelectorAll when you have many div with same classname

```js
const box1 = document.getElementById("box1")
const box2 = document.getElementById("box2")

const box = document.querySelectorAll(".box")

const box_1 = document.querySelector("#box1")
const box_2 = document.querySelector("#box1")
```

```css
    <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
```